# How to get a background to fill width (but not height) of screen?

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to achieve a background that will fill the width of any screen but not the height while still maintaining it's proportion. Kind of like the top half of these:

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/189291990563086544/
http://www.pinterest.com/pin/189291990563736487/

This is what I have put in the body but it fills the whole screen. I've called the body homeground in this instance because my other pages have different background

```
   #homeground {
   background:url(../images/hero-bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
```

Could you guys please advise?

Comment: Set a container with the full width and height specified, and fill the container with your background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
background:url(../images/hero-bg.png) no-repeat top center; 
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: Hi Cattla, is there a way to also keep the background fixed?

Comment: I finally figured out what I was after! I played with the percentages of the background size, so for me it was
background size: 100% 700px. Thanks for all your help! :)